# FB SDK (4.5.1) login : Connection Failed

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using FB SDK version 4.5.1 with eclipse to login to Facebook. Sometimes it login successfully, but some other times it gives me this error message " CONNECTION FAILURE". Is this a problem with my Internet connection or code?

Here is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG,"Fb initialzed");
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    //LoginButton loginButton= (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);


 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Log.d(TAG,"Login success");
            Intent I = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Games.class);
            startActivity(I);
        }

           private void showAlert() {
               new AlertDialog.Builder(GameSurvey.this)
                       .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                       .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                       .show();
           }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG,"Login cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(error instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)
                Log.d(TAG,error.toString());
                showAlert();

        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "here");


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_survey);

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            updateUI();
            // It's possible that we were waiting for Profile to be populated in order to
            // post a status update.

        }
    };
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);





}
```

Comment: Do you get this in the `onError` callback? if so, then this is most likely a connection issue.

Comment: @ifaour yes, Can you please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the error in the error handler callback, then you need to react to it (maybe show a notice to the user and request to try again).

A CONNECTION FAILURE error is self-explanatory. If you can find a specific pattern and you are able to repro this consistently on different networks **and** clients as well (e.g. web), then this might be a bug. Otherwise, this is unlikely to be a bug.